# How to handle popup window using selenium

Tags: selenium

I tried to enter some mobile number in popup but it is not working 
 I am using this piece of code

```
String parentWindowHandler = driver.getWindowHandle(); // Store your parent window
        String subWindowHandler = null;

        Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles(); // get all window handles
        Iterator<String> iterator = handles.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            subWindowHandler = iterator.next();
        }
        driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler); // switch to popup window

        // Now you are in the popup window, perform necessary actions here
        log.info("*****************");
        MobileNumber.sendKeys("999");

        driver.switchTo().window(parentWindowHandler);  // switch back to parent window
```

I am able to print star line mentioned in log.info but not able to enter number

[image]

Comment: Can you please share html code ?

Comment: share your email

Comment: Are you sure that you have an actural **window**? The image shows only popup-styled div. And how do you find `MobileNumber`? It's not in your code.

Comment: @FindBy( name="_rcspsignuprhf_WAR_rcspsignuprhfportlet_mobileNo")
 private WebElement MobileNumber;

Comment: Sorry, I"ve asked wrong question. Include in you code snippet that part where you're searching for the MobileNumber. And an html code for login page would be of great help. Also please show an error message if there're any.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below changes :

Write

```
driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler); // switch to popup window
```

inside "**While**" loop.

Answer (score 0):

The element you are trying to enter the text is not yet ready to take the input. Try to give some explicit wait before send keys for the mobile number

```
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(MobileNumber)); 
MobileNumber.sendKeys("999");
```